# window.location.hash becoming empty after page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to JavaScript. I have a Django application having tabs with URLs. When each tab is clicked, the page reloads. To keep the selected tab active after page reload, I am storing an attribute of the URL in `window.location.hash` and then reading that during page reload to access the selected tab.

My code (partially):

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-xs-6">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" id="demoTabs">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a data-url="/tab1/" href="{% url '...' %}" class="nav-link" role="tab">
                <small>...</small>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a data-url="/tab2/" href="{% url '...' %}" class="nav-link" role="tab">
                <small>...</small>
            </a>
        </li>
```

**JS code**

```
$(function() {

    var hash = window.location.hash;
    $('ul.nav a[data-url="' + hash + '"]').tab('show');
    alert(window.location.hash);

    $('#demoTabs li a').click(function(e) {
        window.location.hash = $(this).attr('data-url');
        alert("HASH: " + window.location.hash);
    });
});
```

The "HASH:" alert shows the hash value correctly (`#/tab1/`, `#/tab2/`), but the first alert then shows blank. How can I prevent the value of `window.location.hash` from getting cleared on page reload? Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using..

```
window.location.hash = $(this).attr('data-url')
```

Use..

```
window.location.href += "#" + $(this).attr('data-url');
```

Then `location.reload()`

```
$(function() {
  var hash = window.location.hash;
  //$('ul.nav a[data-url="' + hash + '"]').tab('show');
  alert(window.location.hash);

  $('#demoTabs li a').click(function(e) {
    window.location.href += "#" + $(this).attr('data-url');
    alert(window.location.hash);
    location.reload();
  });
});
```